# Dynamic select box to populate a textfield using AJAX or jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, select

Is there any tutorial or code that help to poulate a textfield from a chosen value from a select box usuig AJAX or jQuery and PHP? Like in the picture ...

[image]

Comment: I think the answer you want is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592574/populate-select-from-other-select-value-using-jquery

Comment: What I wouldn't give for a bit o' Comic Sans right now.

Comment: @Ben [COMIC SAAAAANS!!!](http://www.explosm.net/comics/2301/)

Comment: Ha! I'll bookmark that one ;-)

Comment: @OverZealous : I wouldn't use a Dynamic Dependent Select but from a selected item from a select box, I will go database and get some other data from and add it to the next textfield

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  //Please visit http://www.nokiflores.com
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#country").change(
       function () {
           $("#capital").val($(this).val());
       }
   );
});
</script>
<select id="country" name="country">
  <option value="Delhi" >India</option>
  <option value="manila" >phil</option>
  <option value="tokyo" >japan</option>
</select>

<input type="text" readonly="readonly" value="" id="capital" name="capital" />
```

try this one:
if you want to use php you will do it another way using ajax.
Please visit http://www.nokiflores.com

Answer (score 0):

I guess once you fill Delhi, the script can decide India, not opposite. 
However if you want to make a subset of cities available, for selected country: that makes sense.

To your question, for this you would need a mammoth list of all major countries and there cities.

My approach:
In javascript make a array of 'country'.
Make a csv list for each country (like in.csv, us.csv etc.)

Now using JS populate country option fields.
Once country is selected, fire Jquery to fetch corresponding 'country-code.csv' using ajax. 
Then Simply make a selection list of fetched city-names.

Note: Some people would object on CSV, choose any file format you find appropriate.