# JQuery, change <select> options?

Tags: html, forms, html-select

On my website, I want to make it so that a user can choose a State and City to go to. If the user selects a state, how would I make it so that the city select box would change all of the cities in the `<option>` tags?

For example:

`Virginia` is chosen, so I'd want to change the cites to `Richmond, Arlington, Fredricksburg, etc.`

Comment: This has been asked so many times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5592574/populate-select-from-other-select-value-using-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, depending upon the architecture of your website. My favorite would be to fire off a `$.ajax`, pull the result down, and load it into the next select. That is the most extensible, IMHO, but not the fastest for the end user. If it isn't a huge list (meaning, download speed), you could load the information into arrays or classes and use that to populate the information.

I would probably do something like this:

```
$("#cities option").remove();
$(citylist[$("#state").val()]).each(function() {
    $("#cities").append('<option value="' + this + '">' + this + '</option>');
});
```

Please note, I haven't tested this, so it may not work, but I think it should send you in the write direction.

JMax